# fading in and fading out a dropdown an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fade in and fade out a `<ul>` on a click. I know the method I am using is wrong because it doesn't work, but also because I am pretty sure it's because I need to use `$(this)` instead of the current `$('#innerList')` but I am just not sure what I have to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/tfZXE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.innerList').hide();
    $('.dropLink').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var inner = $('.innerList', $(this).parent());
        inner.fadeToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/tfZXE/12/

I changed the HTML so that every `li` can have its own `innerList`

Comment: could you possibly explain whats going on in this line var inner = $('.innerList', $(this).parent());?

Comment: @kyllle basically im telling it to search for the `.innerList` within the parent entity (the `li`) of the `.dropLink`

Comment: thanks. now if I wanted to fade out the dropdown if the user clicks outside of .innerList how would I go about doing that? If you could just explain what needs to happen that would be great as Im happy to try and create it.

Comment: try `$('*').not($('.dropLink, .innerList')).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.innerList').hide();
}`

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, that's the point of JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#innerList').hide();
        $('.dropLink').click(function(){
            $("#innerList").fadeToggle();            
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/tfZXE/13/ (only needed to use toggle, and not click, cause click doesn't take 2 methods. And also, you forgot to add # in front of one of the id's)